# jquery change css attrbute for the closest div

Tags: jquery, css

I can't really write a correct question so I'll try to explain my problem.
I'm using jquery accordion and I want to overwrite only two values of ui-icon class with:

```
.ui-icon {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

but only in one place:

```
    <div id="accordion" class="P-accordion">
        <h3>header 1</h3>
```

and there are lots of markups on the way which I don't control, so I want to find the line with: `P-accordion` (it's my style) and overwrite under that, the class `ui-icon`.

This is the full path to the element which I click and which I want to see the effect by changing `ui-icon`

```
html > body > div.container-fluid > div.col-md-4.col-md-offset-1.P-col-md > div#accordion.P-accordion.ui-accordion.ui-widget.ui-helper-reset > h3#ui-id-1.ui-accordion-header.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-accordion-icons.ui-state-hover.ui-state-focus > span.ui-accordion-header-icon.ui-icon.fa.fa-arrow-circle-right
```

Comment: use an `id` and control the particular one

Comment: `$('.modal-header.P-modal-header-1 .ui-icon').css()` will target all ui-icons inside that div. Need to see more markup/explain more clearly what you want if that's not specific enough.

Comment: This is working now:  `$('.P-accordion .ui-icon').css({"height": "auto", "width": "auto"});` Thanks for the above code. Ive given wrong details on start.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the correct element using `nth-child` selector, and overwrite it:

```js
$(".P-accordion:nth-child(2) .ui-icon").attr({
  "class": "new-ui-icon"
});
```

```css
.new-ui-icon {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 P-col-md">
    <div id="accordion" class="P-accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset">
      <h3 id="ui-id-1" class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons ui-state-hover ui-state-focus"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon fa fa-arrow-circle-right">a</span></h3></div>
    <div id="accordion" class="P-accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset">
      <h3 id="ui-id-1" class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons ui-state-hover ui-state-focus"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon fa fa-arrow-circle-right">b</span></h3></div>
    <div id="accordion" class="P-accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset">
      <h3 id="ui-id-1" class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons ui-state-hover ui-state-focus"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon fa fa-arrow-circle-right">c</span></h3></div>
    <div id="accordion" class="P-accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset">
      <h3 id="ui-id-1" class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons ui-state-hover ui-state-focus"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon fa fa-arrow-circle-right">d</span></h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't work with the `:nth-child(2)` parameter in my case (I have to remove it), but this code would be good for replacing the whole class, I only needed to overwrite these 2 values: height and width (but I wasn't clear enough with it). So, I just used css() not attr().